# Laravel 5 binding value in bootstrap-slider in edit/Patch

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm implementing [bootstrap-slider](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/) in my CRUD, I have implemented it successfully in Create, the problem is when I try to edit it,

> I want to get the current value from the Model. Idk how to do this.
>   This is for `PATCH`.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h3 class='box-title text-info'>Percentage</h3> 
    {!! Form::input('text','percentage',null,['id'=>'ex8', 'data-slider-id'=>'ex1Slider', 'data-slider-min'=>'0', 'data-slider-max'=>'100', 'data-slider-step'=>'5', 'data-slider-value'=>'50']) !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your form instead of creating a new form. You will bind the form to the model.

```
{!! Form::model('modelname', [options here] !!}
```

All the fields will math the model's property values.

**Edit**

Here is an [example](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/laravel-form-model-binding)

Comment: actually that's the header of the form, and I have no problem with it, My only problem is how to set 'percentage' to actually reflect in the attribute 'data-slider-value'=>'50'

Answer (score 0):

You must used something like this to create a EDIT FORM 
`{{ Form::model($smartphones, ['method'  => 'PATCH', 'url' => 'smartphones/'.$smartphones->id]) }}`

You get by using `$(your_model)['inputID']`...You can use in "data-slider-value"... Something like this

`{{ Form::input('text','mem_ram', null, ['id' => 'mem_ram', 'data-slider-value'=>$smartphones['mem_ram']]) }}`